# How to convert comma separated strings into integers?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

`dic = {"0.0.1": "112,4,087", "00print_lol": "29,551", "021": "2,541", "02":"23"}`

The keys are package names and their values are download counts. But the values can't be converted directly into integers as they are separated by comma.

So, if I use `int(dic["0.0.1"])`, it gives me en error (which is obvious).

I am doing:

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    temp = ""
    for num in v.split(","):
        temp += num
    dic[k] = int(temp)
print(dic)
```

Which gives me `{'0.0.1': 1124087, '00print_lol': 29551, '021': 2541, '02': 23}` and it is the expected result.

Could you please let me know if there is any better way of doing this?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Geno I am getting the expected result with this solution. But is there any other easier/ efficient way of doing this?

Comment: For me, I may use `int(v.replace(',', ''))`, delete all comma then convert.